# How can I make a pop up window (alertbox) if the input isn't valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically what i'm trying to do is that when i hit a button, it will check if something has been written, if it hasn't I would like an alert box to appear. Is this possible? Down below is what I have so far, any tips? (#inputvalue is the id of the values when writing. I created a new function for the process called validateForm. Is this possible to do in Jquery? I supose that what I wrote is more Javascript, because that's mostly what i'm used to...). //Nathalie!

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["#inputValue"].value;
    if ("#inputValue" == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare the variable `x` to empty string...not another hard coded string

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you use jQuery (as you have tagged your question) you could try something like this:

```
$(function(){

    function validateForm(){
        var ele = $("#inputValue");
        if(!ele.val()){
            alert("Name must be filled out")
        }
    }

    $("#btnId").on("click", validateForm);
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    function validateForm(){
        var ele = $("#inputValue");
        if(!ele.val()){
            alert("Name must be filled out")
        }
    }
    
    $("#btnId").on("click", validateForm);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputValue"/>
<input type="button" id="btnId" value="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using the code you provided, you just need to target `#inputValue` properly and use that value in your test.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById('inputValue').value;
    if (x.trim() == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validateForm()">
  <input id="inputValue" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Using jquery, it's basically the same thing. Here's an example using a submit handler in jquery instead of an `onsubmit` attribute in html, and using jquery selectors.

```js
$('form').on('submit',function(e) {
  var x = $('#inputValue').val();
  if (x.trim() == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="inputValue" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Michael Coker said, it would be better if you attach an event listener by script to the form tag:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementsByName("form")[0].addEventListener("submit", function() {
        var value = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
        if (value == "")
        {
            window.alert("Name must be filled out!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `jQuery`.  Unlike some of the answers above, I did not use a form.

```js
//Listen for the click of the button
$(document).on("click", "#enterButton", function(e) {

//Get the value of the input box
  var F_Name = $('[name="FirstNameInput"]').val();
  
  //If it is empty, alert.
  if (!F_Name.trim()) {
    alert('Empty');
  }else{
    //DO SOMETHING WITH THE INPUT, AJAX?
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="FirstNameInput">
<button type="button" id='enterButton'>Enter</button>
```